# Regex : argument in javascript function

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm not very good for regex and this is why I need your help.

I have this style of javascript functions :

```
javascript:Ouvre('/ade/custom/modules/plannings/eventInfo.jsp',-1,-1,28890,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,'','yes','no','no','yes','no','1','1','790','480')
```

or

```
javascript:Ouvre('/ade/custom/modules/plannings/eventInfo.jsp',-1,-1,28746,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,'','yes','no','no','yes','no','1','1','790','480')
```

and I need to recover one argument (28890 or 28746 in these cases). How do I get the fourth argument using regex?

I would like, if possible, give it a name and then use it easily in C #. Like this :

```
var reg = new Regex("REGEX");
var match = reg.Match((string)value);
if (match.Success)
{
    return match.Groups["FourthArgument"].Value;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `string.Split` looks like a better option - the forth element in the returned array should contain that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Regex` for this.

```
var theValue = jsString.split(',')[3];
```

Comment: won't work if the first argument contains a comma. That's not expected for an URL, though. +1

Answer (score 2):

why not use a simple

```
var number = value.Split(',')[3]
```

if your are not familiar with regex